# Snow Leopard 10.6.3 guest install hangs for Virtual Box 3.2.8 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox

I'm having trouble installing Snow Leopard for VirtualBox. I start it up and I get a black screen with a bunch of gibberish. Then it goes to a grey screen with the Apple pinwheel and just hangs. I've tried loading OSX from both an image and as pass through from the CD drive. Both have the same results. Any insights?

Thanks!
Jieren

Comment: As a note: is this on Mac hardware? :D

Comment: If its not on actual OS X hardware, [its not allowed to be asked here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how VirtualBox handles MacOS guest installations, but before you see OSX's gray screen, you should try pressing Cmd+V (on Windows keyboards you should try both Alt+V and if it doesn't work Win+V). It is important the buttons be pressed before you see the gray screen.

Cmd+V will launch MacOS in verbose mode and you better start paying attention, because "bunch of gibberish" attitude when installing MacOS on PC hardware or virtual machines usually doesn't work.

You should see what file/driver/kext MacOS is hanging at and use google (or superuser) to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox builtin EFI boot loader will not work with retails Mac OS X installation. You have to use different, for example empireEFI boot loader to start the Snow leopard installation.

Here is the working method of [Snow leopard on VirtualBox](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-mac-snow-leopard-1063-oracle-virtualbox-32-apple-intel-pc)